# Foreign key mapping in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a table user with id as the primary key and user_type_id as the foreign key which is the primary key to table user_type.
Can someone spot the error in the mapping i have used in User entity?

```
/**
 * Primary Identifier
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="user_type")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_type_id", type="integer")
 * @var integer
 * @access protected
 */
protected $userTypeId;
```

Also Should i give mapping in user_type table.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be quite a lot of errors actually. Firstly: in ZF2 all Annotations are required to be prepended by `@ORM\` so `@OneToMany` => `@ORM\OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn` => `@ORM\JoinColumn`. The `@ORM\Column`-Part isn't even needed in this example, as this will automatically be defined by `@ORM\JoinColumn`

To find out more about precise errors, use the Doctrine-CLI-Tool to validate your Annotation-Schemata

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```